# ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext:org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory'

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

application.yml

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/countries?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
    username: root
    password: 414141
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
      format_sql: true
      dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
    show-sql: true
    open-in-view: false
```

mysql in docker container.
I have this error when I compile. There was no problem running it locally. This happened when I wanted to migrate my database and project to docker.

```
countriesspringbootproject-server-1  | 2023-04-25T09:58:52.475Z ERROR 1 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Failed nagerFactory: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
countriesspringbootproject-server-1  | 2023-04-25T09:58:52.479Z  WARN 1 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exceptiext initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityM
class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Unable to create requested service [org.hii.JdbcEnvironment]
countriesspringbootproject-server-1  | 2023-04-25T09:58:52.497Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stoppin
mysqldb                              | 2023-04-25T09:58:52.575738Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Locathe path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
countriesspringbootproject-server-1  | 2023-04-25T09:58:52.566Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger :
countriesspringbootproject-server-1  | 
countriesspringbootproject-server-1  | Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application wit
countriesspringbootproject-server-1  | 2023-04-25T09:58:52.668Z ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Applica
countriesspringbootproject-server-1  | 
countriesspringbootproject-server-1  | org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFact resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.enronment]
```

```
version: "3.8"

services:

  mysqldb:
    image: mysql
    container_name: mysqldb
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'countries'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '414141'
    volumes:
      - ./mysql/db:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - '3307:3306'
    networks:
      - country-mysql

  server:
    build: .
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb
    networks:
      - country-mysql
networks:
  country-mysql:
```

When I run docker-compose up it gives these errors. What should I do? How can I fix?